# Concerns about the equivalence of R and 2^N

Tags: analysis, equivalence-relations

[image]

In the prove of Theorem 2.35, I don’t understand why it have to construct a F and a G. Why couldn’t we prove **R** is equivalent to 2^*N* by simply doing binary expansion? Also I don’t really quite understand why F and G is equivalent

Comment: No worries, I figured this out.

Comment: I assume they're doing this to guarantee uniqueness of the binary expansion. If you don't do this, you run into injectivity issues... e.g. $0.1 = 0.0111\ldots$

Comment: Don't use pictures to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. [Here's why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/742).